# sending json through post

Tags: json, post, webserver

I have a little problem while I try to send a json from my iphone app to a php server.

I create NSData object

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:test];
```

I send it to the webserver

```
-(void)send:(NSData *)jsonData{



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:[NSURL
                                                 URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/jsonserver/try2.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

My web server

```
<?php
    $json = $_POST['json'];
    $person = json_decode($json);    
    $file = fopen('test.txt','w+');
    fwrite($file, $person);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

my server correctly creates the file in the folder, but the file is empty

(my json file before it is sent to server is something like that ["a","b","c"])

thank you for your help :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't know iPhone development but it looks like you are sending JSON data in the body of the message. To get the body of the message in PHP, you need to use the following line:

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

I would also set the Content-Type header on the iPhone side to "application/json".

I don't know how this works on the iPhone but keep this in mind: POST would normally take parameters and encode them in HTTP query string format in the body of the message and use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as the Content-Type header so make sure the software on the iPhone side is not doing this.

Comment: It would be great if you could +1 my answer and mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Gave your question a +1 and a favorite to make you feel more a part of the community.